# How to represent node weight in GraphViz?

Tags: graphviz, dot

In GraphViz, the width of edges is represented by the `weight` attribute.  In some graphs the nodes can have a weight as well, e.g., in my case the weight of a nodes indicates the number of internal edges after an aggregation step.

Unfortunately, there is no `weight` attribute for nodes.  Nodes do have a `width` attribute, but that is for display purposes only (having a fixed semantics in inches).

Given the above limitations, what is the best way to represent node weights in GraphViz / the DOT language?

Comment: You can add arbitrary attributes to a node, including one named `weight`. However, I assume you would also want the `weight` to change something in the way the graph is visualized. What would that be?

Comment: @DiomidisSpinellis I'm only thinking about representing the graph itself, not how it is displayed (although DOT is commonly used for both purposes).  I believe that what something is should be strictly decoupled from how it is displayed.

Comment: I absolutely agree with decoupling. See my answer based on your clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `weight` attribute to the nodes.  You can then process the graph with *gvpr* based on `weight`.  As an example, consider the following graph.

```
digraph weighted {
    a [weight = 5];
    b [weight = 2];
    c [weight = 12];
    d [weight = 7];

    a -> b -> c -> d;
}
```

You can color its nodes by processing it with *gvpr* with a script, such as the following.

```
N [weight >= 5 ] {color="red"}
N [weight < 5] { color = "blue"}
```

Processing the graph with this script and then passing the result to *dot* with a command such as the following

```
gvpr -c -f t.gvpr foo.dot | dot -Tpng -ocolored.png
```

will generate the following output.

[image]

Comment: Can we just show weights as a label for each node?

Comment: Yes, use the following gvpr command: N {label = name + ": " + weight}